# Unable to Save/Load Keras model in Tensorflow using Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was following [GettingStarted tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/) of Tensorflow using [Colab notebooks](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/_index.ipynb).

After following it successfully, I decided to give saving model a try. I tried to save it like and it worked. (Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51757115/381897) SO answer)

```
# Saving Model to Drive

!pip install -U -q PyDrive

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# Authenticate and create the PyDrive 
client.auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Save Keras Model or weights on google drive
model.save('getting-started-wtih-tf.h5')  
model_file = drive.CreateFile({'title' : 'getting-started-wtih-tf.h5'})
model_file.SetContentFile('getting-started-wtih-tf.h5')
model_file.Upload()

# download to google drive
drive.CreateFile({'id': model_file.get('id')})
```

But couple of weeks later it started to fail with this exception.

```
NotImplementedErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-9fcdb77fc96c> in <module>()
     15 # Save Keras Model or weights on google drive
     16 # tf.keras.models.save_model(model, 'getting-started-wtih-tf.h5')
---> 17 model.save('getting-started-wtih-tf.h5')
     18 model_file = drive.CreateFile({'title' : 'getting-started-wtih-tf.h5'})
     19 model_file.SetContentFile('getting-started-wtih-tf.h5')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.pyc in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   1356     """
   1357     if not self._is_graph_network:
-> 1358       raise NotImplementedError
   1359 
   1360     from tensorflow.python.keras.models import save_model  #pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top

NotImplementedError:
```

I tried to overcome this problem by changing:

```
model.save('getting-started-wtih-tf.h5')
```

line to a TF oriented save statement:

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, 'getting-started-wtih-tf.h5')
```

But now, I am not able to load same model using these:

```
# Loading Model and Reavaluating
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('getting-started-wtih-tf.h5')
new_model.summary()

new_model.evaluate(x_test_gray_scale, y_test)
```

Because I am getting:

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-f7b789f2dd31> in <module>()
----> 1 new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('getting-started-wtih-tf.h5')
      2 new_model.summary()
      3 
      4 new_model.evaluate(x_test_gray_scale, y_test)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/saving.pyc in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    260           weighted_metrics=weighted_metrics,
    261           loss_weights=loss_weights,
--> 262           sample_weight_mode=sample_weight_mode)
    263 
    264       # Set optimizer weights.

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    424     self._setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    425     try:
--> 426       method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    427     finally:
    428       self._setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.pyc in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, distribute, **kwargs)
    523     # One list per output of the model.
    524     self.nested_metrics = training_utils.collect_metrics(
--> 525         metrics, self.output_names)
    526     self.nested_weighted_metrics = training_utils.collect_metrics(
    527         weighted_metrics, self.output_names)

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'output_names'
```

In short my question is, How can I save/load keras models in Tensorflow?

Also, [this is the notebook](https://gist.github.com/bhdrkn/2a6c9e793c7a2dd20afd75765afd98f5) I am working on.